# Daemonize python websocket

Tags: python, django, docker, websocket, daemon

I'm using ubuntu 16, Django 1.9, and running everything on top of docker. I'm making a bitcoin bot for fun just to try and build something to show off. I'm stuck getting the Binance API which is a WebSocket to daemonize correctly. Here is how I'm going about it:

1. Run containers in docker
2. in WebSocket.sh script execute a docker command that runs the scrapping function in the live docker container:

WebSocket.sh:

```
docker exec <container name> <something to run, bash etc...> <args>
docker exec 817d359aff51 python myproject/scrapping.py
```

I'm using this command to run the websocket.sh file:

Terminal:

```
nohup ./websocket.sh script  args > script.out 2>&1
```

However it never gives me back my terminal, and instead indefinitely runs. When I tail -f script.out it shows the correct behavior.

How can I daemonize this task better? I've looked into Django-celery, cron jobs, and the & function but none seem to be what I want. I just want to execute the task from the command line and have it scrape data as a background process. I've determined this is the best way to do it because I can't find any proper way to do it within the Django framework upon startup. If I use **init**.py and use the ready() function it never starts the server, it just scrapes data. Thank you.

Edit: would you recommend starting a new thread in the **init**.py file with the ready() function?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I recommend making an [admin-command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run this command in a separated container, one container run server the other one run WebSocket. In this case, you have Django's context which allows you to use Django-ORM or settings and docker will be responsible for process management which will be complex if you use thread.

Comment: Thank you for the useful suggestion! I actually ended up making a thread in the uwsgi file that is run on startup so that the server also runs and the scraper works.